# Why is the address of a char[512] equal to that char[512]

Tags: c, pointers, char

When I declared a variable

```
char buf[512];
```

What does mean `&buf` ?

It seems equals to `buf` :

```
printf(" buf :  %p %p\n", (void *) buf, (void *) &buf);
```

prints :

```
buf :  0x7ffda6053fe0 0x7ffda6053fe0
```

Comment: What does `char[512] buf` mean? Is it a typo error?

Comment: Not only is that not valid C, if you want to print out a pointer's value in `printf()` and friends, `%d` is not the right format specifier... go back and read the documentation on the function. And see if you can find something about pointer decay while you're doing so.

Comment: Do you mean  char buf[512]; ?

Comment: (http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html might be useful reading)

Comment: Yes,I mean  char buf[512].

Answer (score 0):

it is the address of the 1st element in the array (i.e. address of buf[0]) vs. the address of the array itself (i.e. buf). No big surprise that they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

The address is the same because an array decays into a pointer to the first element when passed, on the other hand, the address-of operator `&` takes the address of the array, the address of the first element and the address of the array itself are the same.

Use `%p` instead of `%d` to print addresses:

```
printf(" buf :  %p %p\n", (void *)buf, (void *)&buf);
```